# difference between build.xml and build-impl.xml

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build.xml, build-impl.xml

I am studying the code of a already build and well-running web app written in java. In that project, I found two files, build.xml and build-impl.xml, which contains different information related to operation that can be taken on project. I am not able to understand

1) why two different files, build.xml and build-impl.xml are required ?

2) which of above two files are mandatory ?

3) who uses those files and when and how ?

4) what exact information does they contain ?

5) are they auto-generated or they have to be created manually ?

Comment: Usually `build.xml` is used for `Apache Ant`, which is a java build tool. And I didn't know `build-impl.xml` until I see your post, I guess this is for `NetBeans`, so do you use `NetBeans` for development ?

Comment: Yes, I use netbeans for development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. why two different files, build.xml and build-impl.xml are required ?

---

> By default, [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/)(a Java library and command-line tool whose mission is to drive processes described in build files as targets and extension points dependent upon each other.) uses `build.xml` as the name for a buildfile.

We need to build our application for the reason, say, suppose we have several classes and if someone wants to download them, one shouldn't download them individually. So, we should package our application into a jar file(a startable jar file would be good for this purpose). Once you are satisfied that your application works properly, you can prepare the application *for deployment outside of your system/IDE/environment*.

Whereas, from [Setting Up a NetBeans Platform Application](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-ant.html) :-

> The `build-impl.xml` file gives you access to the NetBeans Platform
>   infrastructure, such as its "run" target. You will never need to
>   change the `build-impl.xml` file. On the other hand, the `build.xml`
>   file is the Ant script where you will customize, where necessary, your
>   application's build process.

---

> 2. which of above two files are mandatory ?

None of them are mandatory. If you've several class files(or resources), then  you should build your application. Also, if you want to deploy your application outside of your environment, then there comes the use of build jar file. The latter one is by default present in any NetBeans Java application.

> 3. who uses those files and when and how ?

Already answered above. Don't go in depth of *when*, it's just used in building your application. When you'll be building your application manually using Ant(command line), you'll get to know when!

> 4. what exact information does they contain ?

I've provided the link of NetBeans Tutorial on Ant and build above. Go and visit that. That covers what information is contained in the build.xml and the build-impl.xml.

> 5. are they auto-generated or they have to be created manually ?

No, you've both `build.xml` and `build-impl.xml` by default(auto generated when using NetBeans application). And, you will never need to change `build-impl.xml.`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on question no. 4 and 5 ?

Comment: You told me in point#1, that ant makes jar/war, but I am not able to find any war/jar created, even after cleaning and building the project through ant.

Comment: @user2393267 - See how to build a java application through Ant ---> https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html, and did you've target mkdir in your buildfile and then ,`<jar destfile="build/jar/MainClassName.jar" basedir="build/classes">`? Check your build file,

Comment: I don't have any <jar> tag in my build.xml file.

Comment: @user2393267 - That is your issue, you haven't build a jar file. You should do as advised in the previous link I mentioned in the last comment.

Comment: But, I am still able to run the project. Can that be possible without jar being created ?

Comment: @user2393267 - What are you trying to ask? Your project would run despite of a build, it has different uses. Re-visit my answer. Just for the sake of distribution, people opt for a jar file.

Answer (score 3):

Well, these two files are used by netbeans IDE to enforce specific behaviour based on your project preferences. Now on your questions...

1) build.xml includes a reference to build-impl.xml.  This is used to override build.xml with build-impl.xml behaviour. As stated in the file the build.xml is only used by `Clean and Build` commands. As also stated in build.xml `(If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.)`. The build.xml is not so important. The important file is the build-impl.xml.

2) The build-impl.xml is required as it includes instructions to the JVM, to the IDE debugger, to the compiler, to the ant deploy tool among others...

3) Build.xml is used only by `Clean and Build`. Commands such as Run, Debug, and Test only use this build script if the `Compile on Save` feature is turned off for the project. The build-impl.xml is used by the components stated in the previous point.

4) Answered above

5) Both are auto generated by the IDE. You can edit the build.xml but not the build-impl.xml (You dont have to do it because it is auto generated by the IDE).

UPDATE:
The scope of both files is strictly for the Netbeans IDE. To deploy a project away of netbeans you just need to get the extracted jars, or  wars in case of web apps and deploy them directly to the container.

As far as i know there is no direct relation between projects created with Netbeans with those created in Eclipse.

Comment: Is the scope of  build-impl.xml limited to netbeans ? What If I am deploying the project outside of netbeans environment, then does build-impl.xml have any use ? Moreover, how does eclipse provide the facility that netbeans provide through build-impl.xml ?

Comment: @user2393267 see my UPDATE

Comment: Then doesn't eclipse ant build tool. Because as other answer suggests, build.xml is required by ant. If eclipse doesn't use ant, then what does it use to build project.

Comment: Thanks, @Am_I_Helpful, But please answer me the questions, I was posted for you.